# Determine if current PowerShell Process is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: scripting, powershell, 64-bit, 32-bit

When running a PowerShell script on a x64-bit OS platform, how can you determine *in the script* what version of PowerShell (32-bit or 64-bit) the script is running on?

**Background**
Both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of PowerShell are installed by default on a 64-bit platform such as Windows Server 2008.  This can lead to difficulties when a PowerShell script is ran that must target a specific architecture (i.e. using 64-bit for a script for SharePoint 2010, in order to consume the 64-bit libraries).

Related question:

- [What is the best way to program against powershell's x64 vs. x86 variability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602060/what-is-the-best-way-to-program-against-powershells-x64-vs-x86-variability) This question deals with code running against both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures.  My question deals with the case when you want to ensure the script only runs against the correct version.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

If you're shell is running on .NET 4.0 (PowerShell 3.0):

```
PS> [Environment]::Is64BitProcess
True
```

Comment: Shay, thanks for sharing a very useful code snippet. +1  Unfortunately, I'm running on PowerShell v2, but I'm happy to accept this as the answer.

Comment: @ShayLevy No, definitely better to accept the one that's going to be applicable long into the future. In 2018, PowerShell 2 is a lot less relevant.

Answer (score 88):

To determine in your script what version of PowerShell you're using, you can use the following helper functions (courtesy of [JaredPar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602060/what-is-the-best-way-to-program-against-powershells-x64-vs-x86-variability/602275#602275) to an related question):

```
# Is this a Wow64 powershell host
function Test-Wow64() {
    return (Test-Win32) -and (test-path env:\PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432)
}

# Is this a 64 bit process
function Test-Win64() {
    return [IntPtr]::size -eq 8
}

# Is this a 32 bit process
function Test-Win32() {
    return [IntPtr]::size -eq 4
}
```

The above functions make use of the fact that the [size of System.IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size.aspx) is platform specific.  It is 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine and 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine.

Note, it is worth noting that the locations of the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Powershell are somewhat misleading.  The 32-bit PowerShell is found at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`, and the 64-bit PowerShell is at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`, courtesy of this [article](http://www.gregorystrike.com/2011/01/27/how-to-tell-if-powershell-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/).

Comment: based on this answer I found that the most useful way in order to use the value in string is: `[IntPtr]::size * 8`. That will multiply 8 by the size giving you 32/64 depending on architecture, for example: `"$([IntPtr]::size * 8)bit"`

Comment: FYI, to launch a 64 bit process from a 32-bit command line, replace "System32" with "sysnative". 
C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "[IntPtr]::size"

Answer (score 15):

You can use this as well. I tested it on PowerShell version 2.0 and 4.0.

```sh
$Arch = (Get-Process -Id $PID).StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"];
if ($Arch -eq 'x86') {
    Write-Host -Object 'Running 32-bit PowerShell';
}
elseif ($Arch -eq 'amd64') {
    Write-Host -Object 'Running 64-bit PowerShell';
}
```

The value of `$Arch` will either be `x86` or `amd64`.

EDIT:

The caveat is that `Process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables` always returns the environment of the current process, no matter which process you execute it on.

Comment: `Process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables` always returns the environment of the current process, no matter which process you execute it on. Just use `$env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` if you want to access the current environment - this is PowerShell 1.0 up AFAIK. Certainly 2.0. You can list the environment with `ls env:`.

Comment: $Is64bit = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq 'AMD64'

Answer (score 4):

With Windows itself (and PowerShell) now supported on more architectures, like ARM64, it might not always be enough to check whether the application is 64-bit.

`[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` will also return `True` on Windows running on ARM64, so you cannot rely on it if what you really need to know is whether you're running on `AMD64`. To do this, on Windows you can use the following environment variable:

`$Env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`, which returns values like `AMD64`, `Arm64`, or `x86`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Switch([IntPtr]::size * 8) {

32 { <#your 32 bit stuff#> ;break }

64 { <#your 64 bit stuff#> ;break }

}
```