# How to resolve Get-NetConnectionProfile : Provider load failure on x86 Powershell?

Tags: powershell

If I run `Get-NetConnectionProfile` on 64-bit Powershell it works fine. If I run it on 32-bit Powershell I get the following error:

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile : Provider load failure
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_NetConnectionProfile:root/St
   andardCi...nnectionProfile) [Get-NetConnectionProfile], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041013,Get-NetConnectionProfile
```

This is on 64-bit Windows 8.1 with Powershell version 4.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not meant to work on the 32bit shell. Frankly, it shouldn't even allow you to load the module. These commands use core operating system libraries. Since the core o/s is 64bit, the process trying to load these libraries must also be 64 bit. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Very strange that this module is loaded in the 32-bit Powershell to begin with then...

Comment: Well, the manifest that controls loading the module doesn't specify a bitness for the module. But if you think about it, modules don't know ahead of time the bitness of the o/s, so setting this may be a problem.

Comment: find 64-bit Powershell here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588960/determine-if-current-powershell-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit