# How to configure embedded PowerShell session in a C# application to be 64bit

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, automation

In a regular PowerShell window, one can determine if the current shell is x64 or x86 [by examining the boolean environment variable `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588960/determine-if-current-powershell-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit).

Now I did the same but from an embedded PS session in a .NET application. And the output shows the bitness is not 64bit.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        foreach (var res in ps
            .AddScript("$host.version.tostring()").AddStatement()
            .AddScript("[Environment]::Is64BitProcess").AddStatement()
            .Invoke())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res.BaseObject);
        }

        // Outputs:
        // 4.0
        // False
    }
}
```

Using `corflags` and `ildasm`, I made sure the referenced `System.Management.Automation` DLL is v4.0 and `ILONLY`. And even if I invoke my application from an x64 shell (e.g., `PowerShell.exe` x64), the result still indicates `Is64BitProcess == false`. Any hint?

This is important because I want to `Add-PsSnapin` from the embedded session. Without getting the bitness right, the SnapIn can't be loaded.

Comment: If you compile it as a 32-bit application, you're probably being tripped by the [`File System Redirector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it's compiled as "Any CPU". But if I go "force" it to be "X64" in the build configuration, it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just figured it out. In the project properties, If I "force" the build target from `Any CPU` to `X64`, it solved the problem. The embedded PS session correctly shows the bitness is 64bit, and all registered snap-ins are correctly listed.

[image]

I still don't know why `Any CPU` won't work. Maybe it's because the `Prefer 32-bit` checkbox was checked by default for `Any CPU` option.

Answer (score 2):

The bitness of the embedded PowerShell session follows the bitness of the .NET process calling it.

There seems to be no way (using `System.Management.Automation`) to run a 32-bit embedded PowerShell process from a 64-bit parent process or vice versa (although I'm curious if there is one).

If you have no problem with forcing the parent process to 64-bit, and you are wondering why it is running as a 32-bit process, here are possible reasons:

- The platform is set to "x86"
- The platform is set to "Any CPU", and "Prefer 32-bit" is checked
- The platform is set to "Any CPU", and the parent process is a web application running in IIS Express when running from Visual Studio. You can change this in the Visual Studio settings (Tools > Options > project and Solutions > Web Projects > Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express...). Note that, in production (regular IIS, Azure websites, etc.), the parent process will probably run as 64-bit by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but you probably used the 32-bit version of the PowerShell assembly in your project references.

Make sure you reference a 64-bit version of the `System.Management.Automation.dll` assembly.

On a 64-bit Windows installation, you can find the assemblies here:
**32-bit version**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\[PS version installed]\System.Management.Automation.dll
```

**64-bit version**:

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll
```

Comment: That was what I did. I also mentioned in the original post that with `corflags` I made sure the assembly is `ILONLY`.