# Dynamically switch from 64bit to 32bit powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that needs to run in 32bit powershell. I want to, at run time, determine if it is running in 32 or 64 bit powershell, and if 64bit, switch dynamically to 32bit.

Basically the exact opposite of [this.](http://www.cosmonautdreams.com/2013/09/03/Getting-Powershell-to-run-in-64-bit.html)

```
if ($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 -eq "AMD64") {
write-warning "Y'arg Matey, we're off to 64-bit land....."
if ($myInvocation.Line) {
    &"$env:WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile $myInvocation.Line
}else{
    &"$env:WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -file "$($myInvocation.InvocationName)" $args
}
exit $lastexitcode
}
```

But for some reason I can not figure out how to reverse this. Please help.

Comment: You're expecting us to leave this site and go somewhere else in order to see what you're asking, which is not how this site works. Post the code you've tried that isn't working for you here, in the question itself, and then ask a specific question related to that code.

Comment: You might find [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588960/determine-if-current-powershell-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit) useful.

Comment: @KenWhite I was not aware this was against the rules. I am sorry to have inconvenienced you so greatly.

Comment: Aside from that, what problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 which requires a 32bit environment. I am performing the check at the beginning of the script to automatically switch to the appropriate environment (if it is not already).

Answer (score 3):

The 32-bit version of PowerShell on a 64-bit system resides in

```
$env:WINDIR\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

So test if running on a 64-bit system:

```
if ([Environment]::Is64BitProcess) {
  write-warning "Switching to 32-bit.PowerShell."
  if ($myInvocation.Line) {
    &"$env:WINDIR\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Non -NoP -NoL $myInvocation.Line
  }else{
    &"$env:WINDIR\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Non -NoP -NoL -file "$($myInvocation.InvocationName)" $args
  }
  exit $lastexitcode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([IntPtr]::size -eq 8) {
    Write-Host "Switching to 32bit..."
    if ($myInvocation.Line) {
        &"$env:WINDIR\SysWOW64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile $myInvocation.Line
    }else{
        &"$env:WINDIR\SysWOW64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -file "$($myInvocation.InvocationName)" $args
    }
    exit $lastexitcode
}
```