# Execution Policy error when running powershell script from autohotkey

Tags: powershell, autohotkey, executionpolicy

I have a simple autohotkey script

```
!+l:: RunWait, PowerShell -NoExit -C "Import-Module D:\projects\changescreensaver\changescreensaver.psm1; Set-ScreenSaverTimeout 1;"
```

But it won't let me load my ps profile or do the import-module and gives me an execution policy error:

```
Import-Module : File D:\projects\changescreensaver\changescreensaver.psm1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is
disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
```

On my terminal, `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` returns

```
C:\Users\someone>Get-ExecutionPolicy  -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

but within my script, returns

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

I can just pass it `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`, but I'd still like to understand: Why are my ExecutionPolicy values different when invoking PS from AHK?

Comment: No, but I realized that AHK is running 32-bit powershell, while my terminal is 64-bit, so I guess that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You found the source of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56718479/45375) - your AHK is 32-bit and therefore runs the 32-bit PowerShell executable, while your terminal (console window) runs the 64-bit executable - but let me add some background information.

In **Windows PowerShell** (unlike in PowerShell *Core*) the **execution policies are stored in the *registry***, namely at:

- `LocalMachine` scope:

  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell`, value `ExecutionPolicy`
- `CurrentUser` scope:

  - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell`, value `ExecutionPolicy`

While **32-bit and 64-bit applications** share the same `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive, they **have distinct `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` subtrees**.

Therefore, **only the `LocalMachine` scope has separate execution-policy values for the 32-bit and 64-bit executables.**

In other words: If your execution policy were set at the *user* level (`-Scope CurrentUser`), the problem would not arise.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my terminal was running 64-bit powershell while AHK was using 32-bit, discovered by running:

```
[Environment]::Is64BitProcess
```

based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588960/determine-if-current-powershell-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit).