# What does the ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} Powershell variable contain on a 32bit/x86 system?

Tags: powershell, x86

Simple question:

If I use the ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} variable in a PowerShell script on a 32-bit system does it return "C:\Program Files" or is it undefined?

On a x64 system it will be mapped to "C:\Program Files (x86)" when running in both x64 and x86 mode. I don't have a 32bit system to test on, but I hope that it will be mapped to the "C:\Program Files" folder so I can use it to refer to x86 programs on any system.

Comment: If you're developing for both architectures you should really test on both.

Comment: I have a request in for an x86 environment but figured this would be documented somewhere. Couldn't find it online anywhere :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to program against powershell's x64 vs. x86 variability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602060/what-is-the-best-way-to-program-against-powershells-x64-vs-x86-variability)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` is not defined on a 32-bit machine.  You can test against `$null` to verify that.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the -ne operator "Null coalescing" from http://stackoverflow.com/a/17647824/17373 to do this: `$dir = (${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}, ${env:ProgramFiles} -ne $null)[0]`. Not pretty but it works.

Comment: Just to be precise, on a 32bit system, the environment variable is not defined, so for example if you do `dir env:` it won't be present. However, PowerShell returns $null if you try to access a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: @StephenD Yeah, that's more accurate.  I've updated the answer.